# R/Shiny: JSON Reading Libraries

Tags: r, json, dataframe, shiny, jsonlite

I am trying to put "data" into a dataframe but can't figure out an easy way to do this in R. Here is just a snippet from the entire JSON.

```
[
    {
        "something": 555,
        "timestamp": "aTimeStamp",
        "data": [
            {
                "company": "something1",
                "quarter": 1,

            },
            {
                "company": "something2",
                "quarter": 1,
            }
    }
]
```

I can do this quite easily in Python utilizing

```
data = json.load(filepath)
for i in data["data"]:
   //do stuff
```

But I can't find an easy way to do this in R. All guides I have found look like they are utilizing JSON from a nosql database instead of something like this where we have "something" and "timestamp" included.

UPDATE:

```
    df_json <- fromJSON(json_data, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) 
    # get a glimpse of the list_json2 object
    glimpse(df_json)
    glimpse(as.data.frame(df_json["data"])
```

This code yields `$ data           <list> [<data.frame[21 x 20]>]` but I can't figure out how to take the information found in data and put it in a data frame correctly.

Comment: There are some problematic parts in your json data. First, there is a missing `]` and secondly,  the comma after the quarter. `"quarter": 1,`  should be `"quarter": 1`. Is  it a typo? or your exact json data?

Comment: @maydin the actual JSON is around 1000 lines so I just tried to put a short snippet up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert it into a dataframe,you can use `unnest()` from `tidyverse` library like,

```
  library(jsonlite)
  library(tidyverse)
    
  df_json <-fromJSON(json_data, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) 
  out <- df_json%>% unnest(data) %>% data.frame()
  out
```

gives,

```
  something  timestamp    company quarter
1       555 aTimeStamp something1       1
2       555 aTimeStamp something2       1
```

Data:

```
[
    {
        "something": 555,
        "timestamp": "aTimeStamp",
        "data": [
            {
                "company": "something1",
                "quarter": 1

            },
            {
                "company": "something2",
                "quarter": 1
            }
    ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time maydin! Would there be a way to only receive `company` and `quarter` in the dataframe and remove `something` and `timestamp`?

Comment: ahhh I did `out <- df_json["data"]%>% unnest(data) %>% data.frame()` and it worked perfectly. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: `out[,-c(1,2)]` cancels out first two columns. Or just `df_json[,"data"][[1]]` gives only the data without needing `tidyverse`.